# Mysql full-text-search query execution

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

Greerings everyone

Just would like to know the difference in the following queries :

```
select*, MATCH ( thread_title, first_post ) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance from posts where MATCH(`thread_title`, `first_post`) AGAINST('apple'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

and

```
select*, MATCH ( thread_title, first_post ) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance from posts   ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

## Edited

Actually both are getting the right results on the top, the second is getting a lot more results and the first gets the right results only. The second is taking a lot of time to execute end the first is much faster. Dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT  *,
        MATCH (thread_title, first_post) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM    posts
ORDER BY
        relevance DESC
```

will return all records from your table (with `relevance = 0` for those containing no `'apple'`).

This query:

```
SELECT  *,
        MATCH (thread_title, first_post) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM    posts
WHERE   MATCH (thread_title, first_post) AGAINST ('apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
        relevance DESC
```

will only return records containing `'apple'` in either `thread_title` or `first_post`. All relevances returned will be greater than `0`.

The second query is faster because you, most probably, have a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on `posts (thread_title, first_post)` and the matches are searched using that index.

Answer (score 1):

The first query will only return the results for rows that match the restriction you set (ie. those results that contain apple in either thread_title or first_post), whereas the second will return all rows, regardless of the fact that they contain a match for your search query or not.